# Splunk : Spath searching the JSON array

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have below two JSON events where under "appliedConditionalAccessPolicies", in one event policy1 has results =failure and policy2 has results=notApplied. In the other event the values are reversed.

Now I'm trying to get the event where the policy1 has the status="failure", it gives both the events

```
index=test
| spath path="appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}" | search "appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.displayName"="policy1" "appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.result"="failure"
```

It looks like Its searching within all the elements in the array.
How can I ensure It searches both the conditions on each element of the array and return the event which has the element satisfying both the conditions.

Events :

```
 appDisplayName: App1
   appId: aaaa-1111-111aeff-aad222221111
   appliedConditionalAccessPolicies: [ 
     { 
       displayName: policy1
       enforcedGrantControls: [
         Block
       ]
       enforcedSessionControls: [
         SignInFrequency
         ContinuousAccessEvaluation
       ]
       id: f111113-111-400c-a251-2123bbe4233e1
       result: failure
     }
     { [-]
       displayName: policy2
       enforcedGrantControls: [ [-]
         Block
       ]
       enforcedSessionControls: [ [-]
       ]
       id: sdsds-8c92-45ef-sdsds-c0b2e006d39b
       result: notApplied
     }
   ]
   
   appDisplayName: App1
   appId: aaaa-1111-111aeff-aad222221111
   appliedConditionalAccessPolicies: [ 
     { 
       displayName: policy1
       enforcedGrantControls: [
         Block
       ]
       enforcedSessionControls: [
         SignInFrequency
         ContinuousAccessEvaluation
       ]
       id: f111113-111-400c-a251-2123bbe4233e1
       result: notApplied
     }
     { [-]
       displayName: policy2
       enforcedGrantControls: [ [-]
         Block
       ]
       enforcedSessionControls: [ [-]
       ]
       id: sdsds-8c92-45ef-sdsds-c0b2e006d39b
       result: failure
     }
   ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.displayName` and `appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.result` are multi-value fields so you need to do something that determines if the search matches the same index of both multi-value fields.

**Here is a way using `mvfind`:**

And `mvfind` gives you the multi-value field index so you can compare them, but from my testing mvfind hates field names like `appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.displayName` and `appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.result` so you need to rename them before you can use them with `mvfind`.  This works for me:

```
| rename "appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.displayName" as displayName
| rename "appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.result" as result
| where mvfind(displayName,"policy1")=mvfind(result,"failure")
```

Here is a full example that you can play with:

```
| makeresults
| eval data="
{\"appDisplayName\":\"App1\",\"appId\":\"aaaa-1111-111aeff-aad222221111\",\"appliedConditionalAccessPolicies\":[{\"displayName\":\"policy1\",\"enforcedGrantControls\":[\"Block1\"],\"enforcedSessionControls\":[\"SignInFrequency\",\"ContinuousAccessEvaluation\"],\"id\":\"f111113-111-400c-a251-2123bbe4233e1\",\"result\":\"failure\"},{\"displayName\":\"policy2\",\"enforcedGrantControls\":[\"Block2\"],\"enforcedSessionControls\":[],\"id\":\"sdsds-8c92-45ef-sdsds-c0b2e006d39b\",\"result\":\"notApplied\"}]}
###
{\"appDisplayName\":\"App2\",\"appId\":\"aaaa-1111-111aeff-aad222221112\",\"appliedConditionalAccessPolicies\":[{\"displayName\":\"policy1\",\"enforcedGrantControls\":[\"Block1\"],\"enforcedSessionControls\":[\"SignInFrequency\",\"ContinuousAccessEvaluation\"],\"id\":\"f111113-111-400c-a251-2123bbe4233e1\",\"result\":\"notApplied\"},{\"displayName\":\"policy2\",\"enforcedGrantControls\":[\"Block2\"],\"enforcedSessionControls\":[],\"id\":\"sdsds-8c92-45ef-sdsds-c0b2e006d39b\",\"result\":\"failure\"}]}
"
| makemv data delim="###"
| mvexpand data
| spath input=data
| fields - data 

| rename "appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.displayName" as displayName
| rename "appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.result" as result
| where mvfind(displayName,"policy1")=mvfind(result,"failure")
```

**Here is a way using `mvzip`:** (thanks to @warren)

You can join the multi-value fields together nad then just search for the string that contains both values.  It looks like mvzip also hates field names like `appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.displayName` and `appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.result` so you need to rename them before you can use them with `mvzip`.  This works for me:

```
| rename "appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.displayName" as displayName
| rename "appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.result" as result
| where mvzip(displayName,result)="policy1,failure"
```

Here is a full example that you can play with:

```
| makeresults
| eval data="
{\"appDisplayName\":\"App1\",\"appId\":\"aaaa-1111-111aeff-aad222221111\",\"appliedConditionalAccessPolicies\":[{\"displayName\":\"policy1\",\"enforcedGrantControls\":[\"Block1\"],\"enforcedSessionControls\":[\"SignInFrequency\",\"ContinuousAccessEvaluation\"],\"id\":\"f111113-111-400c-a251-2123bbe4233e1\",\"result\":\"failure\"},{\"displayName\":\"policy2\",\"enforcedGrantControls\":[\"Block2\"],\"enforcedSessionControls\":[],\"id\":\"sdsds-8c92-45ef-sdsds-c0b2e006d39b\",\"result\":\"notApplied\"}]}
###
{\"appDisplayName\":\"App2\",\"appId\":\"aaaa-1111-111aeff-aad222221112\",\"appliedConditionalAccessPolicies\":[{\"displayName\":\"policy1\",\"enforcedGrantControls\":[\"Block1\"],\"enforcedSessionControls\":[\"SignInFrequency\",\"ContinuousAccessEvaluation\"],\"id\":\"f111113-111-400c-a251-2123bbe4233e1\",\"result\":\"notApplied\"},{\"displayName\":\"policy2\",\"enforcedGrantControls\":[\"Block2\"],\"enforcedSessionControls\":[],\"id\":\"sdsds-8c92-45ef-sdsds-c0b2e006d39b\",\"result\":\"failure\"}]}
"
| makemv data delim="###"
| mvexpand data
| spath input=data
| fields - data 

| rename "appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.displayName" as displayName
| rename "appliedConditionalAccessPolicies{}.result" as result
| where mvzip(displayName,result)="policy1,failure"
```

Comment: I usually go the [`mvzip`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/MultivalueEvalFunctions#mvzip.28X.2CY.2C.22Z.22.29) route, myself :)

Comment: @warren  Actually that would have been a great way to do it.  You should write an answer.    If you don't want to, let me know and I will add that to this answer.

Comment: your answer is great! Go ahead and add the `mvzip` option herein so OP doesn't have to choose between two answers :)